# How to remove a property from nested javascript objects any level deep?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

Let's say I have nested objects, like:

```
var obj = {
    "items":[
        {
            "name":"Item 1", 
            "value": "500",
            "options": [{...},{...}]
        },
        {
            "name":"Item 2", 
            "value": "300",
            "options": [{...},{...}]
        }
    ],
    "name": "Category",
    "options": [{...},{...}]
};
```

I want to remove the options property from any level deep from all the objects. Objects can be nested within objects, and arrays as well.

We're currently using Lodash in the project, but I'm curious about any solutions.

Comment: maybe this helps https://github.com/jonschlinkert/omit-deep

Answer (score 9):

There is no straight forward way to achieve this, however you can use this below function to remove a key from JSON.

```
function filterObject(obj, key) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            filterObject(obj[i], key);
        } else if (i == key) {
            delete obj[key];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

and use it like

```
var newObject = filterObject(old_json, "option");
```

Comment: Hmm our codebase is in strict mode, and I'm getting the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode.

Comment: @void is there a way to do this without recursion, I keep getting 'RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'  even with the similar solution posted here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/323670

Comment: @erotavlas maybe you need to pass only a part of the object and not the complete object. This will reduce the number of iterations.

Comment: It seems delete key; should be delete obj[key];

Comment: if key contains object as value then @sboyd solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62564765/5994481) is better structured.

Answer (score 6):

Modifying the above solution, To delete "**dataID**" which appears multiple times in my JSON . mentioned below code works fine.

```js
var candidate = {
  "__dataID__": "Y2FuZGlkYXRlOjkuOTI3NDE5MDExMDU0Mjc2",
  "identity": {
    "__dataID__": "aWRlbnRpdHk6NjRmcDR2cnhneGE3NGNoZA==",
    "name": "Sumanth Suvarnas"
  },  
};

candidate = removeProp(candidate, "__dataID__")

console.log(JSON.stringify(candidate, undefined, 2));

function removeProp(obj, propToDelete) {
   for (var property in obj) {
      if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
         delete obj.property
         let newJsonData= this.removeProp(obj[property], propToDelete);
         obj[property]= newJsonData
      } else {
          if (property === propToDelete) {
            delete obj[property];
          }
        }
    }
    return obj
}
```

Comment: is `delete obj.property` a typo?

Answer (score 6):

A little modification of void's answer that allows for deletion of propertise which are also objects

```
function filterObject(obj, key) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (i == key) {
            delete obj[key];
        } else if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            filterObject(obj[i], key);
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We now use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for data processing tasks like this. It's very powerful once you wrap your head around it. Here is how you'd answer your questions

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const prune = (input) => objectScan(['**.options'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ parent, property }) => {
    delete parent[property];
  }
})(input);

const obj = { items: [{ name: 'Item 1', value: '500', options: [{}, {}] }, { name: 'Item 2', value: '300', options: [{}, {}] }], name: 'Category', options: [{}, {}] };

console.log(prune(obj));
// => 3

console.log(obj);
// => { items: [ { name: 'Item 1', value: '500' }, { name: 'Item 2', value: '300' } ], name: 'Category' }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues. So, I developed the following library. Please see the source code of the library on [GitHub](https://github.com/thedolphinos/utility4js), and you can download it using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@thedolphinos/utility4js).

You can use the function `removePropertiesDeeply` together with `isInitialized` as below to remove all non-initialized properties (such as an empty object, empty array, empty string, or non-finite number).

```
const {removePropertiesDeeply, isInitialized} = require("@thedolphinos/utility4js");

const object = {
  a: null,
  b: "",
  x: {
    a: null,
    b: ""
  },
  y: [],
  z: [
    null,
    "",
    {a: null, b: ""},
    [[{a: {b: null, c: ""}}]],
    "abc"
  ]
};

removePropertiesDeeply(object, (x) => !isInitialized(x));
console.log(JSON.stringify(object)); // See that the object becomes {"z":["abc"]}.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I got it resolved. I hope my solution might be helpful to someone.

I use Es6 `...` spread operator to do a shallow copy of an object and made null to property I was not interested.

```js
const newObject = {
   ...obj.items,
   ...obj.name,
   options: null // option property will be null.
}
```

Comment: `undefined` would be more accurate, as you're removing info

Comment: This does not work for the "any level" part of the question. You do mention it's shallow, but that's not the question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function omit(source) {
  return isArray(source)
    ? source.map(omit)
    : isObject(source)
    ? (({ options, ...rst }) => mapValues(rst, omit))(source)
    : source;
}
```

as with lodash, that's an easy thing, also you can specify the key via an param like this

```js
function omit(source, omitKey) {
  return isArray(source)
    ? source.map(partialRight(omit,omitKey)))
    : isObject(source)
    ? (({[omitKey]: _, ...rst }) => mapValues(rst, partialRight(omit,omitKey)))(source)
    : source;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove properties given a condition using following function:

```js
// Warning: this function mutates original object
const removeProperties = (obj, condition = (key, value) => false) => {
  for (var key in obj) {
    const value = obj[key]
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue
    if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
      removeProperties(obj[key], condition)
    } else if (condition(key, value)) {
      delete obj[key]
    }
  }
  return obj
}
```

Examples:

```js
// Remove all properties where key is equal to 'options'
removeProperties(someObject, (key, value) => key === 'options'))


// Remove all properties where key starts with 'ignore_'
removeProperties(someObject, (key, value) => key.startsWith('ignore_'))


// Remove all properties where value is null
removeProperties(someObject, (key, value) => value === null))
```