# How to remove all instances of a specific key in an object?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have a large javascript object which contains multiple instances of a key. I'd like to remove all instances of this key and value from the object.

I have this function which allows me to find a nested object, though I'm not sure how to modify it to get all objects, and to delete the keys from the object. Can someone help me with this?

```
var findObjectByKey= function (o, key) {
  if (!o || (typeof o === 'string')) {
    return null
  }
  if (o[key]) {
    return o[key];
  }

  for (var i in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      var found = findObjectByKey(o[i], key)
      if (found) {
        return found
      }
    }
  }
  return null
}
```

This is an example object where I'd like to remove all keys `d`:

```
var a = {
  b: {
    c: {
      d: 'Hello',
    },
    d: 'Hola',
    e: {
      f: {
        d: 'Hey'
      }
    }
  }
}

// To become
var a = {
  b: {
    c: {},
    e: {
      f: {}
    }
  }
}
```

Also, is there a way we could do this with Ramda by chance?

Comment: what about `Array.prototype.filter()`?

Comment: You want to change the object in place or return a new object?

Comment: I'd rather return a new object.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607701/how-to-remove-a-property-from-nested-javascript-objects-any-level-deep

Answer (score 3):

Using `R.when`, if `o` is an object, apply `R.pipe` to it. In the pipe, remove the property from the object using `R.dissoc`. Iterate other properties with `R.map`, and try to remove the property for each of them.

```js
const removePropDeep = R.curry((prop, o) => R.when(
  R.is(Object),
  R.pipe(
    R.dissoc(prop),
    R.map(removePropDeep(prop))
  ),
  o
))

const a = {
  b: {
    c: {
      d: 'Hello',
    },
    d: 'Hola',
    e: {
      f: {
        d: 'Hey'
      }
    }
  }
}

const result = removePropDeep('d')(a)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Be aware. This will turn arrays to objects https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.28.0#?const%20removePropDeep%20%3D%20R.curry%28%28prop%2C%20o%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20R.when%28R.is%28Object%29%2C%20R.pipe%28R.dissoc%28prop%29%2C%20R.map%28removePropDeep%28prop%29%29%29%2C%20o%29%2C%0A%29%0A%0AremovePropDeep%28%27b%27%2C%20%7Bhi%3A%20%7Ba%3A%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%7D%7D%29

Answer (score 1):

To alter the object in place you can just change:

```
return o[key];
```

to:

```
delete o[key];
```

To return a new object, make a new object with `Object.assign()`, then delete the key in question. Then recurse on the rest of the keys:

```js
var a = {
  b: {
    c: {
      d: 'Hello',
    },
    d: 'Hola',
    e: {
      f: {
        d: 'Hey'
      }
    }
  }
}

var findObjectByKey= function (o, key) {
  if (!o || (typeof o === 'string')) {    //  assumes all leaves will be strings
    return o
  }
  o = Object.assign({}, o)                // make a shallow copy
  if (o[key]) {
    delete o[key]                         // delete key if found
  }
  Object.keys(o).forEach( k => {
      o[k] = findObjectByKey(o[k], key)   // do the same for children
    })
  return o                                // return the new object
}

let obj = findObjectByKey(a, 'd')
console.log(obj)
```