# Is there a way to remove all occurrences of the "__typename" property in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I want to remove all occurrences of "__typename" from dictionary "data". I used one of the function from this stackoverflow post: [How to remove all instances of a specific key in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429021/how-to-remove-all-instances-of-a-specific-key-in-an-object) and it outputs the correct answer but my compiler displays [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW5p5.png). I am new to Typescript and I am having a hard time finding a solution.

---

**Code snippet**:

```
import * as R from ramda;

// Dictionary "data"
const data = {
    "subscription": {
        "id": "10",
        "subscribers": [
            {
                "id": "2017",
                "username": "potato1",
                "__typename": "UserType"
            },
        ],
        "unsubscribers": [
            {
                "id": "2022",
                "username": "potato2",
                "__typename": "UserType"
            }
        ],
        "__typename": "SubscriptionType"
    },
    "__typename": "Subscribe"
};

// Function from linked stackoverflow post, works but get a syntax error (see screenshot)
const removePropDeep = R.curry((prop, data) =>
    R.when(
        R.is(Object),
        R.pipe(R.dissoc(prop), R.map(removePropDeep(prop))),
        data
    )
);

console.log(removePropDeep("__typename", data));
```

---

**Expected**:

```
{
    "subscription": {
        "id": "10",
        "subscribers": [
            {
                "id": "2017",
                "username": "potato1",
            },
        ],
        "unsubscribers": [
            {
                "id": "2022",
                "username": "potato2",
            }
        ],
    },
};
```

---

**Error message:**

```
"Function implicitly has return type 'any'
because it does not have a return type annotation
and is referenced directly or indirectly
in one of its return expressions."
```

Comment: Please do not link _images_ of error messages. Instead copy and paste the relevant output to your question. See http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: `__typename` is a private field needed in (e.g.) apollo to understand the schema, you shouldn't really need to remove it IMHO... however, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51380645/4099454

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a function overload definition using an interface, because the function is curried. I've used the same definition of `R.dissoc` ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/removepropdeep-xrv2iq?file=/src/index.ts)).

**Note:** I've replaced `R.map` with `R.mapObjIndexed` because TS has a hard time infering that in this case `R.map` iterates an object.

```
interface iRemovePropDeep {
  <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(prop: K, obj: T): Omit<T, K>;
  <K extends string | number>(prop: K): <T extends object>(
    obj: T
  ) => Omit<T, K>;
}

const removePropDeep: iRemovePropDeep = curry((prop, data) =>
  when(
    is(Object),
    pipe(dissoc(prop), mapObjIndexed(removePropDeep(prop))),
    data
  )
);
```