# Remove all instances of a key in a nested object (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, json, object, key

Let's take the following object:

```
{
"isbn": "123-456-222",  
"author": {
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "firstname": "Jane",
    "coAuthor": {
        "lastname": "Johnson",
        "firstname": "Jim"
    }
},
"editor": {
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "firstname": "Jane"
},
"title": "The Ultimate Database Study Guide",  
"category": ["Non-Fiction", "Technology"]
}
```

What's the best way to delete/remove all instances of the `firstname` key(s) in javascript?

Comment: Can you add some explanations pls? what json you have and what json you want

Comment: He did provide all necessary info...

Comment: not sure if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429021/how-to-remove-all-instances-of-a-specific-key-in-an-object

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607701/how-to-remove-a-property-from-nested-javascript-objects-any-level-deep